# Exception occurred while using @EnableConfigurationProperties and @Configuration annotations in conjunction

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

While using `@EnableConfigurationProperties({XYZ.class})` and `@Configuration` **over the** `XYZ.class` annotations in conjunction in spring boot, I am getting following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.example.configproperties.Database' available: expected single matching bean but found 2: database,database-com.example.configproperties.Database
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveNamedBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1271)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:494)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:349)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:342)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1172)
    at com.example.configproperties.ConfigPropertiesApplication.main(ConfigPropertiesApplication.java:20)
```

Here are my code snippets:

```
@EnableConfigurationProperties({Database.class})
@SpringBootApplication
@PropertySource("classpath:database.properties")
public class ConfigPropertiesApplication {
 ......
 ......
}
```

I have added `@EnableConfigurationProperties({Database.class})` as I want to populate entries in `Database.class` to be populated through external properties file given by `@PropertySource("classpath:database.properties")`

My Database.class is as follows:

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "database")
public class Database {
    
    String url;
    String userName;
    String password;
```

Following are my observations:

1. If I remove the `@Configuration` from the `Database.class` then the bean gets populated with the required values
2. If I totally remove `@EnableConfigurationProperties({Database.class})` (and add back `@Configuration`)then also the bean gets populated with the required values.
3. So, this means that, if both the entries are present, then spring throws an exception mentioned above during the startup.
4. If I just have `@EnableConfigurationProperties` (Note: I have removed the Database.class input from the annotation) and added back `@Configuration` over `Database.class` then also it works fine and the bean gets populated with the properties.

So my first question is: What happens when `@EnableConfigurationProperties({Database.class})` is present and why spring throws(if `@Configuration` annotation is also present):

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException
```

My second question is: Why is it mentioned in the doc that `@EnableConfigurationProperties` is necessary as my observation on the contrary shows that it is enough to have `@Configuration` to populate the properties from external file into the bean

I have also read somewhere that it is important to have `@EnableConfigurationProperties({Database.class})` annotation only once and over the `Startup` class. I don't understand this why, though I get that following configuration doesn't work as intended:

```
@EnableConfigurationProperties({Database.class})
//@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "database")
@PropertySource("classpath:database.properties")
public class Database {
}
```

With the above configuration, spring throws following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.example.configproperties.Database' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:351)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:342)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1172)
    at com.example.configproperties.ConfigPropertiesApplication.main(ConfigPropertiesApplication.java:19)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "database")
public class Database {
    String url;
    String userName;enter code here
    String password;

}


@EnableConfigurationProperties({Database.class})
@SpringBootApplication
public class ConfigPropertiesApplication {

}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate with some explanation? This does not answer my question